# Show $\mu(E) = 2\lambda(E\cap[0,\infty))$, $\mu = \lambda \circ u^{-1}$ (image measure)

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $u:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, u(x)=|x|$. Consider the image measure $\mu = \lambda \circ u^{-1}$. Show $\mu(E) = 2\lambda(E\cap[0,\infty))$.

---

Proof

$$
u^{-1}(E) = \{x\in\mathbb{R}:u(x)\in E\} =\\ \{x\in\mathbb{R}:u(x)\in E\cap(-\infty,0)\} \bigcup \{x\in\mathbb{R}:u(x)\in E\cap[0,\infty)\} = \\ 
u^{-1}(E\cap(-\infty,0)) \cup u^{-1} (E\cap[0,\infty))
$$

Notice that $u^{-1}(E\cap(-\infty,0)) $ and $u^{-1} (E\cap[0,\infty))$ are disjoint.

The Lebesgue measure will therefore be

$$
\lambda(u^{-1}(E)) = \lambda(u^{-1}(E\cap(-\infty,0))) + \lambda(u^{-1} (E\cap[0,\infty)))
$$

Now I'm very close! I'm almost 100 % certain that above is the same as $2\lambda(E\cap[0,\infty))$ but I can not figure out what the formal argument will be?

Answer (score 1):

But $u^{-1}(E\cap(-\infty,0))=\emptyset.$ Maybe this works better:

$\displaystyle \mu(E)=\int_{\mathbb R^+}1_E(y)d\mu(y) =\int_{\mathbb R}(1_E\circ u)(x)d\lambda(x)=\int_{\mathbb R}1_E(|x|)d\lambda(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^+}1_E(x)d\lambda(x)+\int_{\mathbb R^-}1_E(-x)d\lambda(x)=\int_{E\cap \mathbb R^+}d\lambda(x)+\int_{E\cap \mathbb R^+}d\lambda(x)=2\lambda (E\cap\mathbb R^+)$

because $1_E(|x|)=\begin{cases}
       1& |x|\in E \\
      0& |x|\notin E 
    \end{cases}=\begin{cases}
       1& x\in E\quad  \text{or}\ -x\in E\\
      0& \text{otherwise} 
    \end{cases}$

Comment: Thanks, but I'm told that this can be solved very simple. Just be doing something similar to what I do.

Comment: If you read through my proof, you will see it $is$ simple. Just uses definitions.

Comment: Yes, I actually understand your point. By simple I meant: using basic set theory, axioms of a measure  and the definition of Lebesgue on the reals.

Comment: Right. But all I am using is the definition of image measure, and properties of the absolute value and Lebesgue measure. So I do not really understand your comment. I do not think your  proof will  work because $u^{-1}(E\cap(-\infty,0))=\emptyset.$ You have not used the definition of image measure or the absolute value. But I will be happy to delete my answer and wait for a better one!

Comment: No, why delete the answer? 
I will try to improve mine. It is very late right now. I will probably go to bed and give it another try tomorrow.

Comment: It is good to have an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. Here is a little simplification.

The function $u(x)=|x|$ induces a measure on $([0,\infty),\mathscr{B}([0,\infty))$. By monotone class arguments it is enough to see how the push forward of $\lambda$ under $u$ (i.e.$\lambda\circ u^{-1}$)  acts on sets of the form $[0,a]$, $a>0$.

$f^{-1}([0,a])=\{x:|x|\leq a\}=[-a,a]$ and so
$\lambda(f^{-1}([0,a])=\lambda([-a,a])=2\lambda([0,a])$

This $\lambda\circ u^{-1}=2\lambda$ restricted to $([0,\infty),\mathscr{B}([0,\infty))$.

Comment: What you have written I understand. But I can not see how that is going to help me going  from 
$\lambda\left(u^{-1}(E)\right)=\lambda\left(u^{-1}(E \cap[0, \infty))\right)$ to the finish line $\mu(E)=2 \lambda(E \cap[0, \infty))$?